# Improve Accuracy of Email Classification?

Tags: performance, nlp, logistic-regression, text-classification, tf-idf

I am building an email classification model. Currently, I am using NLTK's stopwords and lemmatization during the pre-processing of data. Following are the parameters for TF-IDF vectorizer that I am using:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf= True, 
                       min_df = 5, 
                       norm= 'l2', 
                       ngram_range= (1,2), 
                       stop_words ='english')
```

I am using LogisticRegression for classification.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression  # Logistic Regression - (Best Performance Till Now)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['Rejoined_Lemmatize'], df['Product'], random_state = 0, test_size = 0.2)
X_train_counts = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)

clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X_train_counts, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(tfidf.transform(X_test)) # Predicting using our Model

print(metrics.classification_report(y_test,y_pred, labels= df.Product, target_names=df['Product'].unique())) # Print Results
```

I am getting the following results from the above code:

```
                                precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Bank account or service       0.45      0.52      0.48        46
Checking or savings account       0.60      0.52      0.56        56
            Money transfers       0.60      0.52      0.56        56
               Student loan       0.60      0.52      0.56        56
              Consumer Loan       0.86      0.86      0.86        64
                Payday loan       0.91      0.96      0.94        55
            Debt collection       0.88      0.71      0.79        62
                   Mortgage       0.88      0.71      0.79        62
           Credit reporting       0.86      0.86      0.86        64
               Prepaid card       0.81      0.80      0.81        65
                Credit card       0.60      0.52      0.56        56

                   accuracy                           0.79    198000
                  macro avg       0.79      0.79      0.78    198000
               weighted avg       0.80      0.79      0.79    198000
```

How Can I improve this accuracy??

Note - I am working on the "**Consumer Complaints Dataset**". I am only using 3300 rows from that database and I have balanced my database i.e 300 emails from each category

11 categories * 300 emails = 3300 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The response to the question could be improved if sample data is provided. However, with the given information, the following points could help in exploring the problem better.

- The recall values for first 4 classes are identical upto second decimal. One could hypothesize that the underlying test data may have tokens that are common to them. One could further hypothesize that this could be a multi label multi class problem and not just multi class problem. To explain further, it could be possible that emails referring to sudent loan also have text about their bank account/service, money transfer, credit card etc. Thus one email can be mapped to more than one class. **For such problems, a cleaner but harder way of classifying can be found [here]**(https://www.listendata.com/2018/05/sentiment-analysis-using-python.html).
- The recall and precision for class: *payday loan* are the highest. One could hypothesize that the word "payday" is relatively unique and hence model is able to classify this class the best. A further inspection into the most important features will help in confirming this hypothesis. **The inference is that this model is performing well with Payday loan class**.
- The recall and precision for *debt collection* and *mortgage* are identical up to second decimal. It is intuitive to understand that emails that speak about debt collection will have mortgage related tokens in it, as long as the debt is to do with mortgages. **The inference is to discuss this with the business owner to club both these classes into one class.**